# C File management error

Tags: c, file, file-io

I wanted to write, read and print to and from the same file. But when the program executes, it can write but it can't read or print the data I have written. When I execute the program, it stops working after writing to the file. I have verified that the file (penny.txt) contains data after the write operation.

I don't know where this is going wrong - how can I read and print the data?
I'm quite new to this, so please take that in mind when answering.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char ch;
    char penny[50],pen[50];
    FILE *Object;
    Object = fopen("Penny.txt","w+");

    fgets(penny, sizeof penny, stdin);
    fprintf(Object,penny);
    fscanf(Object,"%s",pen);
    printf("%s",pen);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: An advice :at the end you should fclose(Object);

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! To help us help you, please post example input and output and describe how it differs from what you want.

Comment: Flush output after write

Comment: @wazy How do i do that?

Comment: Just add "fflush(Object);" after "fprintf()". Before you can "fscanf()" a file, you have to reset or reopen it.

Comment: Use fflush after your fprintf

Comment: Please use parentheses in sizeof function: fgets(penny, sizeof(penny), stdin);

Comment: @Axel yeah i tried as you said but when i execute the program it is printing garbage

Comment: You need to seek back to the beginning of `Object`. You're reading at the end of the file.

Comment: @alex kemper: thank you alex, I Closed the file and then reopened it, then it is working fine. :)

Comment: There are several functions to position the read position of a file. Look at a [reference](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C_Programming/C_Reference/stdio.h) candidates are rewind, fseek, fsetpos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    //char ch;//unused!
    char penny[50],pen[50];
    FILE *Object;
    Object = fopen("Penny.txt","w+");

    fgets(penny, sizeof penny, stdin);
    fprintf(Object,"%s", penny);//it troubled indicator(%) is included
    fflush(Object);//Buffer flush : So that there is no wrote
    rewind(Object);//rewind the position of access to the file
    fscanf(Object,"%s",pen);
    printf("%s",pen);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You're at the end of the file when you call `fscanf()`. Use [`fseek`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696699/functions/fseek.html) to return to the beginning:

```
/* this ignores a whole host of other issues */
fprintf(Object,penny);
/* optional: fflush(Object); */

/* after the call to fprintf you're at the end of the "stream" in this case,
 * go back to the beginning:
 */
fseek(Object, 0, SEEK_SET);

/* now we have something to read! */
fscanf(Object,"%s",pen);
printf("%s\n",pen);
```

You did not notice this problem due to a complete lack of error checking. `fopen`, `fprintf`, and `fscanf` all have error conditions listed, and all use their return value to signal a problem. You ignore these return values at your own peril.

Answer (score 0):

You need to Use [fseek()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fseek/) to move back the file current position inside the file.

```
int fseek ( FILE * stream, long int offset, int origin );
```

Reposition stream position indicator
Sets the position indicator associated with the stream to a new position.

```
stream
```

Pointer to a FILE object that identifies the stream.
    offset
Binary files: Number of bytes to offset from origin.
Text files: Either zero, or a value returned by ftell.

```
origin
```

Position used as reference for the offset. It is specified by one of the following constants defined in  exclusively to be used as arguments for this function:

```
Constant    Reference position
SEEK_SET    Beginning of file
SEEK_CUR    Current position of the file pointer
SEEK_END    End of file
```

*

try this:

```
#include<stdio.h>

 int main()
    {
        char ch;
        char penny[50],pen[50];
        FILE *Object;
        Object = fopen("Penny.txt","w+");

        fgets(penny, sizeof penny, stdin);
        fprintf(Object,penny);//now the file is in EOF
        fseek(Object,-1*(strlen(penny),SEEK_CUR);//<===move back |penny| in the file
         /* optional or:fseek(Object,0,SEEK_SET);<===move to start of file */
        fscanf(Object,"%s",pen);
        printf("%s",pen);
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: [`fgets`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/fgets.html) may not have read `sizeof penny` bytes.